# Show that $\int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{\prod_{u=0}^n (1+\alpha_u\,x)}\,dx = ...$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, logarithms, contour-integration, branch-cuts

**Prove that, by complex analysis,**
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{\prod_{u=0}^n (1+\alpha_u\,x)}\,dx =  \frac{1}{n! \,2^{n+1}}\sum_{m=0}^n (-1)^{m+1}\binom{n}{m}\alpha_m^{n-1}\log^2(\alpha_m).$$ The real analysis approach is fairly straightforward, but rather tedious. As for complex analysis, I am unsure. My approach obviously fails: Begin by letting
$$\oint_C f(z)\,dz$$
be a contour integral over a semi-circular arc where the branch along the negative real axis of the logarithm is chosen (perhaps this is the issue) and the contour is deformed into a keyhole contour with the orgin cut out. Then, by Cauchy's theorem, one can show a similar relation with the result. The issue lies when we integrate on the upper and lower branches, we get a $-x$ term on the denominator. How can I traverse this issue? At first I thought it is obvious to instead choose a different branch of the logarithm but I do not know how this would work. A hint is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: *Hint.* Assume WLOG that $\alpha_k$'s are positive reals. Then compute $$\oint_{C}\frac{(\operatorname{Log} z)^2}{\prod_{k=0}^{n}(1+\alpha_k z)} \,\mathrm{d}z$$ where $\operatorname{Log}$ is the complex logarithm with the branch cut $[0,\infty)$ and $C$ is the keyhole contour.

Comment: Also, I believe that the proposed equality is not true in general. Indeed, for $n\geq1$ and distinct positive reals $\alpha_0,\dots,\alpha_n$, we have $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log x}{\prod_{k=0}^{n}(1+\alpha_k x)}\,\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{m=0}^{n}\frac{\alpha_m^{n-1}\log^2 \alpha_m}{\prod_{k\neq m}(\alpha_m-\alpha_k)}.$$

Comment: I got it-- thank you.